# SQLAlchemy - querying multiple tables and returning nested objects

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

Suppose we have a simple one-to-many relationship between Company and Employee, is there a way to query all companies and have a list of employees in the attribute of each company?

```py
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Company.id))
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```py
>>> result = db.session.query(Company).join(Employee).all()
>>> result[0].Employee
[<Employee object at 0x...>, <Employee object at 0x...>]
```

The size of result should be same as the number of rows in company table.

I tried the following and it gives tuple of objects (which makes sense) instead of nice parent / child structure:

```py
>>> db.session.query(Company, Employee).filter(Company.id = Employee.company_id).all()
```

It's not hard to convert this into my desired object structure but just wanted to see if there's any shortcut.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    employees = db.session.query(Company, Employee).filter(Company.id = self.id).all()
    self.employee_list = ['{0} {1}'.format(c.first_name, c.last_name) for c in employees]
```

Then you could access a employee name with `Company.employee_list[0]`

Comment: This is a terrible idea as it will lazy load the values instead of the desired approach (using join) described in the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the relationship in the parent class:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    employees = relationship('Employee', lazy='joined') # <<< Add this line
```

Then you can query it without a join:

```
companies = session.query(Company).all()
print(companies[0].employees)
```

Documentation:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
db.session.query(*Company.__table__.columns, *Employee.__table__.columns).filter(Company.id = Employee.company_id).all()
```

it returns a not nested result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).